# Adjoint Matrix Invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

If matrix A is invertible, is its adjoint matrix also always invertible?

The book "Elementary Linear Algebra" by Anton and Rorres use the terms adjucate matrix, adjoint matrix, and classical adjoint matrix interchangeably. Is there a difference between them? From  my limited experience, I think there is. In this problem I am referring to the adjoint matrix as the transpose of the cofactor matrix from A.

Comment: The answer is yes. And yes, there is a difference between these terms in that the "adjoint" is commonly used to refer to the [Hermitian adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint).

Comment: The adjugate matrix satisfies $A \operatorname{adj}(A) = \operatorname{det}(A) I$. So both matrices are invertible iff the determinant of $A$ is nonzero.

Comment: I can find at least three books entitled "Elementary Linear Algebra" (one written by Anton & Rorres, one by Larson and the other by Spence) on Amazon. You should at least state clearly the name of the author.

Answer (score 0):

By Cramer's rule, the adjoint of an invertible matrix equals its inverse times its determinant. Now, is that invertible?